# How should this be listed

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to handle this?

Say I have a listing of events but for each event I have two pieces of information like the name of the event and the date of the event.

Example:

George's Fundraiser
October 20, 2011

Eileen's Company Event
October 21, 2011

I thought about doing each of those as listed items inside a unordered list but didn't know if I should force a line break after the first line or if there is a better suggested way of handling this. Only thing to keep in mind is the event name will have a css style applied to it.

Comment: This seems more like a personal preference and argumentative. If it was more "how do I display it below the event name using CSS", this would be a good question.

Comment: If you are placing them in an <ul> you wouldn't need to force the line break as long as you don't force the <li>'s to become inline or float them. Try something and see if it works for you. There are hundreds of ways to do something and most aren't right or wrong, just how they work out for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could do it with a [definition list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) `dl` and add `dt` und `dd` elements.

If you want to stick to an unordered list you could use `span` elements for styling - or even better: the title has a special - strong - meaning in this context. You might want to add some more semantics by wrapping the title with `strong` (this helps you with styling though…).

Comment: +1 definition list. When you have a pair of data in the format of a term and definition. In this case, event and date.